Is super-exponential complexity useful in practice?
Exponential time-complexity has a useful application in "practical" CS: NP-problems, NP-complete problems. Knowledge about this obviously helps in everyday programming.
Can you give an example of practical usefulness of super-exponential time-complexity?

Please see this
